# How to get updated value of a variable outside of setOnItemSelectedListener?

Tags: java, android

**What I am trying to do ?**

I am trying to get the value of data member `totalPrice` outside of `OnItemSelectedListener` which is updated inside of `OnItemSelectedListener` by the function `populate()`.

Code:

*MainActivity*

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   private double totalPrice;
   private void populate(){
      // some private code
      totalPrice += 10; // this shows the updated value
   }

   private void initSpinner(){

      Spinner date = findViewById(R.id.Date);

      ArrayList<String> dateContent = new ArrayList<>();
      dateContent.add("2020-06");
      dateContent.add("2020-05");

      ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.date_layout, R.id.dateItem, dateContent);
      date.setAdapter(adapter);

      date.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener(){
          @Override
          public void onItemSelected(AdapterView adapter, View view, int i, long lng){
              for (int idx = 0; idx < 5; idx++)
                  populate();
          }
          @Override
          public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView){ }
      });
  }

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      initSpinner();
      System.out.println("Total: "+totalPrice); // this doesn't show updated value
  }
}
```

Comment: your code does't making sense to me ... I.e What you are extactly doing if the date selected ?... as far as I know from your code you are just adding 50 to  previous value of totalPrice whenever the user selects a date from spinner ..

Comment: @PraveenSP I have reduced the complexity of the code in order to just get to the problem. I just want to get the updated value of `totalPrice` after returning from `SetOnSelectedItemListener` I.e I am not able to get the updated value (50) in the `onCreate` method

Comment: @PraveenSP Why doesn't this statement `System.out.println("Total: "+totalPrice);` print 50 ? Instead it prints 0

Answer (score 0):

You can't get the updated value in `onCreate` because this calls only once when the activity created.
For getting the latest value you can try this

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   private double totalPrice;
   private void populate(){
      // some private code
      totalPrice += 10; // this shows the updated value
      System.out.println("Total: "+totalPrice); 
   }

   private void initSpinner(){

      Spinner date = findViewById(R.id.Date);

      ArrayList<String> dateContent = new ArrayList<>();
      dateContent.add("2020-06");
      dateContent.add("2020-05");

      ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.date_layout, R.id.dateItem, dateContent);
      date.setAdapter(adapter);

      date.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener(){
          @Override
          public void onItemSelected(AdapterView adapter, View view, int i, long lng){
              for (int idx = 0; idx < 5; idx++)
                  populate();
          }
          @Override
          public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView){ }
      });
  }

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      initSpinner();

  }
}
```

Comment: How is that a solution ? Read my question carefully including comments.

Comment: or create a listener which will call from populate() method and display the data there

Comment: Take a look at my answer it does the job :)

Answer (score 0):

<s>So, basically what happens is the method won't execute unless you select some value from the dropdown.</s>

You were right actually the method is being called but unfortunately, there is some kind of delay maybe it will be called only after views are drawn... so first you need to call the line after some seconds

Use this to print the value in **onCreate**

```
 @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      initSpinner();
      new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Log.d("Output","TotalPrice : "+totalPrice);
            }
        },500); // it causes half second delay

  }
```

Comment: "So, basically what happens is the method won't execute unless you select some value from the dropdown." That is not right I know this because I included this statement `System.out.println("working");` inside `SetOnSelectedItemListener` and guess what ? It displays the message without having to select the value from the dropdown.

Comment: @Ahtisham You were right ...I Changed my answer check it once

Comment: What do you think about my answer ? Isn't it better ?

Comment: Yeah I checked it.. If you ask me, I could have gone with the similar kind of approach if I was implementing it but in your question you mentioned getting it outside the onSlectedItemListener and you were given a print statement there ... so that made me to produce this answer ...

Answer (score 0):

Finally fixed it:

Added a TextView and set its value to the updated value of totalPrice inside `setOnItemSelectedListener`.

So first create a `TextView` in layout then include it in Activity:

```
private TextView total;

private void initTotal(){
  total = findViewById(R.id.Total);
}
```

Then define a `setTotal()` function:

```
private void setTotal(double newTotal){
  total.setText("Total: "+newTotal); 
}
```

After that call `setTotal()` inside `setOnSelectedItemListener`.

Here is a full code:

*MainActivity*

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView total;   
    private double populate(double totalPrice){
        // some private code
        return totalPrice += 10;
    }        
    private void setTotal(double newTotal){
       total.setText("Total: "+newTotal);
    }

    private void initSpinner(){

        Spinner date = findViewById(R.id.Date);
        // code to setup adapter
        date.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener(){
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView adapter, View view, int i, long lng){
                double totalPrice = 0;
                for (int idx = 0; idx < 5; idx++)
                   totalPrice = populate(totalPrice);
                setTotal(totalPrice); // set the value of TextView whenever new value is updated
            }
            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView){ }
       });
   }

   private void initTotal(){
      total = findViewById(R.id.Total);
   }

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      initTotal();
      initSpinner();
   }
}
```